# japserserver The request resource is not available HTTP 404

Tags: tomcat, jasperserver

I have installed **Apache Tomcat 7.0 Tomcat7** ,and test it server and everything is working great, then i have installed **jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.1** and choose the existed tomcat that i have installed before .

But when i access the this url : http://localhost:8081/jasperserver/
it results with this error : [image: JasperServer-error]

so here i will eidt the questions to show error logs :

**tomcat7-stdout.2015-05-02.log**

*Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.SQLDataSourceWrapper.getConnection(SQLDataSourceWrapper.java:46)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ...*

**catalina.2015-02-02.log:**

*org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/jasperserver] appears to have started a thread named [quartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.*

Answer (score 2):

Check if PostgreSQL server running in my case starting PostgreSQL server and then restarting the Jasper Report server did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

it seems that jasper server did not start. The first you should check tomcats Manager app - if there is jasperserver up and running. If not, try to start it.

The next step should be edit your comment and add there log from catalina.out (logs in tomcat) with error message

Comment: Many thanks. There is problem with connections. If it is freshly installed jasper, the problem seems to be with jasper database. Try reinstall it and take higher care of these part of installation. After it you should try of the connections into jasper database if it works. We use native postgres and there are no problems with it.
[link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/installation-steps-installer-distribution) - here are Installation steps and also nice part about db configuration